# Which episode in season 3 showing Eren having to seal a rock with hardening?

Tags: attack-on-titan

I can’t remember when they showed Eren having to seal a rock with hardening, flashback or not. It was in season three of *Attack on Titan*.

What episode is it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Attack On Titan season 3, episode 8. Eren uses the titan hardening ability to protect his comrades in the underground of the Reis Chapel.

[image]

He isn't sealing a rock thou

Answer (score 0):

The episode you where referring to, is episode 13 of Season 3 Part 2.Titled, The town where everything began.